Vertex AI SDK not working on Firebase Cloud Functions
I'm trying to use the vertex-ai sdk on my Firebase Function, but keep getting the below error (a very vague message as this does not tell me what the issue is - there is no stack trace, this is the only error I receive in the Logs Explorer on GCP):

GoogleGenerativeAIError: [VertexAI.GoogleGenerativeAIError]: exception posting request to model
at /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/vertexai/build/src/functions/generate_content.js:49:15
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async generateContent (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/vertexai/build/src/functions/generate_content.js:39:22)
at async /workspace/lib/api/prompt.js:22:21

The code that I'm trying to run (a simple test):
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {setGlobalOptions} = require("firebase-functions/v2");

import { VertexAI } from '@google-cloud/vertexai';

setGlobalOptions({ region: "australia-southeast1" });

exports.promptTest = onRequest({cors: true}, async (request, response) => {
  const vertex_ai = new VertexAI({project: 'my-project-id', location: 'australia-southeast1'});
  
  const model = 'gemini-1.5-pro-preview-0409';

  const generativeModel = vertex_ai.preview.getGenerativeModel({
    model: model
  });

  const prompt = `Give me an idea for a camping trip`;
  const req = {
    contents: [{role: 'user', parts: [{text: prompt}]}],
  };

  await generativeModel.generateContent(req).then(content=>{
    console.log("Data: ",content);
    try{
        const result = content.response.candidates.at(0).content.parts.at(0).text;
        response.send(result);    
    } catch (e){
        console.log(e);
        response.send(e);
    }
}).catch(err=>{
    const error = `Generating Content Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
    console.log(error);
    response.send(error);
});
});

The try...catch returns the following error:

Generating Content Error:
{"stackTrace":{},"name":"GoogleGenerativeAIError"}

I have enabled all the Vertex AI API components on my GCP account and have tested using the cloud CLI (it worked as expected).
API_ENDPOINT="australia-southeast1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
PROJECT_ID="my-project-id"
LOCATION_ID="australia-southeast1"
MODEL_ID="gemini-1.5-pro-preview-0409"

curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://${API_ENDPOINT}/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${LOCATION_ID}/publishers/google/models/${MODEL_ID}:streamGenerateContent" -d '@request.json'

I hope somebody else has run into this problem and found a solution.


Show how you tested with the CLI. 2) Show the entire error / stack trace.


@JohnHanley Updated the question accordingly. No stack trace data to share unfortunately (the error provided is all I get in Logs Explorer), making it much harder to understand what the problem is.

Have you considered modifying your code to catch exceptions and log details? During debugging, you can return the stack trace as a JSON response.

Unfortunately, it only returns this:
jsonPayload: {
name: "GoogleGenerativeAIError"
stack_trace: {
}
}

What only returns that? Do you know how to create and manage exception handlers? Details help. Edit your question with details and not via comments.

I've updated the question with the detail as requested.

You are testing locally, but failing in the cloud. In addition, your local test uses a different set of code and request method. That means different execution environments, authorization credentials, etc. Test your code locally using the same service account that the function is using in the cloud.
